# Low intensity EM waves and doppler effect in Thomson Scattering

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, scattering, doppler-effect

We know that when the wave model of light was being used in physics there was Thomson Scattering Model to explain the interaction between a free electron and a light.

The Thomson Scattering was explaining the force that acts on an electron when a light hits it, with the force that the electrical field component of that light possesses. (Rather than billard ball explanation)

However, I do not understand Thomson Scatter in relation to  Doppler Effect and Low-Intensity waves.

For the wave model of the Photoelectric effect, it was clear for me to understand where was the wave model wrong when explaining the necessity of the quanta of energies. But,

**How was Thomson wrong when talking about Doppler shift and low-intensity waves not being able to explain the movement of electrons?**

I know for a fact that low-intensity waves were insufficient to supply energy for an electron to have the speed and kinetic energy it is supposed to have.

I am not sure how built-up energy by low-intensity waves have been thought to be a supply of energy for the acceleration of electron in the first place and how is this related to the Doppler shift by Thomson.